# Could ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor work on 2 tasks concurrently?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

In my code I use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor initialized with pool size of 10 threads, and I have jobs that are being executed.

In my logs I seem to see a problem where the same thread seems to be working on 2 different jobs concurrently !!

Could this be??

Comment: How did you figure out that the same thread is executing two jobs concurrently?

Comment: no, it can't - probably you have named the logger which you use to identify the threads using the same name. show us the code

Comment: you should not be worrying about the thread of your pool. moreover, do you have evidences that 2 jobs (define jobs, btw) are being executed by the _same_ thread at the _same_ time.

Comment: I know this because one task tries to lock for reading a ReentrantReadWriteLock lock and a different task tries to access the same lock but for writing. 
When the 2nd task tries to lock for writing I get a warning that tells me that the same thread already locked for reading!